# How is a J-Head Extruder Head attached to the Prusa i3 rework?

Tags: reprap, prusa-i3, prusa-i3-rework

I am building a Prusa i3 Rework, and I haven't been able to find out how to attach my J-Head extruder (see below), at the moment it's just kind of held there by pressure, but it seems there are two holes on ether side of it; not sure if they're meant to hold it in place, but it seems that way.

[image: Image of two holes in the side of the x-carriage with a J-Head Extruder just below it, with ring exposed]

Any suggestions as to what I should use to hold it in place?  This is definitely a part that gets moved around alot.

**update**

[image: Image of two holes in the side of the x-carriage with a J-Head Extruder just below it (pushed up a little bit)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the hotend may not be all the way in, are you sure it's not stuck?

If it's stuck and you can get it in further, those holes should go directly through the smaller ring on top of the J-Head.  You just need to run a machine screw into each hole to secure the hotend. The screw will need to at least be flush with the other side to work correctly.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean...there's an indentation at the top and that seems to go higher when I push it in to the J-Head extruder.  So I just push that in further and the screws will hold it up from there?

Comment: The ring I'm talking about appears to just be visible in your picture, you have a long way to go to line that up with the holes.  Are you able to get it in far enough to do that?

Comment: It looks that way, but I didn't really push it that far up.

Comment: Is that better (see second image above)?

Comment: Yes, placing two screws in should hold it fine.